# Text marked after leaving textarea in Angular

Tags: angular, textarea, selection, lost-focus

I have a textarea where I want the user to make a selection 
I use the event (select) I get all details of the selection but I want the selection to stay marked.

So the user can change it after and see what he marked in the past

```
getSelectionDetails1(startIndex: number, endIndex: number) {
    if (window.getSelection) {
      this.problem.selection.text = window.getSelection().toString();
      this.problem.selection.from = startIndex
      this.problem.selection.to = endIndex;
    }
  }

  showAnnotationQuestion1(val: string) {
    if (val == 'Yes' || val == 'Somewhat') {
      this.question2 = "Please mark the relevant chunk in the sentence (the problem the organism faces "
      this.textAreaText1 = this.text
    }
    else {
      this.question2 = ""
      this.textAreaText1 = ""
    }
    this.problem.answer = val
  }
<textarea readonly (select)="getSelectionDetails1(textarea1.selectionStart, textarea1.selectionEnd)"
      #textarea1 class='textarea1'>{{textAreaText1}}</textarea>

 .textarea1::selection{
        background-color:purple;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem :
Instead of using select event and highlight selection , I put all my selection into spans and add class=selected for which were filling the condition .

```
  <div *ngFor="let word of words ;let i=index" (mousedown)='getfirstIndexAndRemovePreviousSelection(i,"problem")'
          (mouseup)='updateSelectedField(i,"problem")'}">
          <span [ngClass]="{'selected': word.selected == true}">
            {{word.text}}
          </span>
        </div>


 span.selected{
        background-color:cadetblue;
      }
```